# github pages scripts not loading on custom domain only

Tags: gatsby, github-pages

I have my website (Developed in **Gatsby**) hosted on github pages and it works properly. However, if i try to use a custom domain, some scripts won't load. I tried to deploy the site in netlify using the same github repo and the scripts won't load as well.

My github website: https://rodrigorochadev.github.io/pathfinderdesigns

Netlify website: https://quirky-jones-2ae5a3.netlify.app/

Any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a solution. In `gatsby-config.js` my `pathPrefix` was set to the name of my repo. I've changed it to `/`, and it is now working on Netlify.

Answer (score 1):

@Ferran Buireu's answer also worked for me

my package.json had

```
"deploy": " gatsby build --prefix-paths && gh-pages -d public",
```

and gatsby-config.js had

```
  pathPrefix: '/',
```

also make sure your CNAME file also has the correct URL